# Why is my external hard drive being remounted during IO?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, hardware, external-hdd

I frequently use a particular external hard drive. Today, during a backup where I am writing a large number of files to the external hard drive, it keeps getting unmounted and immediately re-mounted. This has never happened before.

I can hear a faint click or blip on the drive each time this happens. Is the external hard drive dying?

Is there a way to take it easier on the hard drive, eg. a parameter for rsync?

#### Edit / Update 1

I think a cable problem is highly unlikely: It's a mini USB and I have found these much more reliable than the now-standard micro USB.

A power problem seems most likely. The mini USB that plugs into the external drive actually splits into two standard USB male plugs, which I believe is done for power reasons. I always plugin both, but **I suspect the older laptop I was attaching it to simply wasn't putting out enough power to its USB ports.**

#### Edit / Update 2

The filesystem (FAT, or more precisely W95 FAT32 LBA) was corrupted. I'm still not sure if that was a cause of my problem, or a symptom of hard drive failure or insufficient power.

Comment: It's look like power problem, try different usb, cable with two connectors on PC side.

Comment: It can also be due to a loose USB port or cable.

Comment: This is either a failing HDD, or that the USB port isn't supplying enough power, and that you need to connect AC power to the external enclosure, or use a POWERED USB hub.